# Xbee power issue

Tags: power, xbee

I want to power xbee s2 module through atmel 328p digital output pin. And I am powering atmel 328p IC using 3.7 li-ion cell 5500 mAh. In sleep mode atmel consume current in micro Amp but xbee consuming around 40 mA. I want to reduce it. I tried xbee in power down mode but its not working for me. Is der any way to switch xbee automatically with as atmel sleep & wake-up. Circuit works properly when I power xbee through 3.7 v li-ion cell but consume power continuously.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to determine why your Xbee is not being switched into power down mode.

But, if you wish to turn the Xbee power off using the Arduino then there are many ways of doing this. One method is shown on the diagram below {[**from here**](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m697820.aspx)}. This requires two transistors and three resistors. Almost any small transistors would work. Good choices if buying new components would be BC337 / BC817 for T1 and BC327 / BC807 for T2. The first part number in each pair is a through hole part and the second number is the equivalent surface mount part. If buying these try to get the -40 suffix versions, although in this case any version would work OK.

This circuit was drawn for use with a PIC processor controlling a 12V supply, but the Arduino works equally well controlling a 3.7V LiIon supply. The load is shown as a light bulb - that's where you'd connect the XBee.

[image]

Input low turns 1 off which turns T2 off. To enable/disable the XBee you have to raise / lower the input pin.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a sleep mode, e.g. PIN sleep, in order to reduce the power consumption of the Xbee. At the hardware level, the XBee uses pin 9 as a control pin. This pin can be used to sleep the radio: setting it to 3,3V (“high” or “asserted”) causes the radio to sleep; setting it to 0V (“low” or “deasserted”) wakes the radio up. You can find some useful hints on the following websites http://citizen-sensing.org/2013/08/xbee-sleeping/ or https://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Designing_a_Sleeping_XBee_Sensor  or here http://www.johnhenryshammer.com/WOW2/pagesHowTo/xbeeSeries1.php#index.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE! Can you please edit your answer to include how exactly to do this and any relevant code/diagrams/etc.? Thanks!